# groupby with apply: ffill(), bfill

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe where I want to use bfill().ffill(). From other questions and answers I know bfill()/ffill() doesnt really work on groupby, one should use apply() as follows:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,2,1,2,1,2], 'order':[2,2,3,1,1,3], 'a':[2,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'b':[np.nan,7,3,8,np.nan,4]})
for i in temp.columns:    
   temp.loc[temp['group']==1, i ] = temp.sort_values(by =['order'], ascending = [True]).groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
```

this works.

However when I run that on my dataset it always crashes because of memory. Any advice on how to use an alternative or manage RAM better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself

selecting the required column [i] after groupby works

```
for i in temp.columns:    
   temp.loc[temp['group']==1, i ] = temp.sort_values(by =['order'], ascending = [True]).groupby('group')[i].apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
```